# paste function for an element of an object returns NA

Tags: r

```
data<-read.csv("advanced_r_programming/data/MIE.csv")

LongitudinalData<-function(n_sub){
  structure(n_sub, class = "LongitudinalData" )
}

make_LD<-function(x){
  LongitudinalData(sum(as.logical(unique(x$id))))
}

print.LongitudinalData<-function(x){
  paste("Longitudinal dataset with", x[n_sub], "subjects")
  }

x<-make_LD(data)

print(x)
```

So this returns "Longitudinal dataset with NA subjects"  How do I get it to return the number stored in the field on the object?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. Specifically, it would be helpful if you would use `dput()` to generate a text version of the class in question, and post it as part of your question.

Comment: Even more specifically, at a bare minimum we'd need the output from `dput(foo)` where `foo` is the thing you're trying to call this function on.

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I've made the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

In the S3 object system, objects are constructed using the `list()` function as an argument to `structure()`. Your code will work as expected if you make the following changes.

```
LongitudinalData<-function(n_sub){
     structure(list(n_sub = n_sub), class = "LongitudinalData" )
}

make_LD<-function(x){
     LongitudinalData(sum(as.logical(unique(x$id))))
}

print.LongitudinalData<-function(x){
     paste("Longitudinal dataset with", x["n_sub"], "subjects")
}

data<-read.csv("./data/MIE.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,nrows=100)
x<-make_LD(data)
print(x)
```

...and the output, when we read the first 100 rows of the MIE.csv file:

```
> data<-read.csv("./data/MIE.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,nrows=100)
> x<-make_LD(data)
> print(x)
[1] "Longitudinal dataset with 1 subjects"
>
```

Here is what happens when we read the entire `MIE.csv` file, and cross-check it with an SQL query.

```
> data<-read.csv("./data/MIE.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> x<-make_LD(data)
> print(x)
[1] "Longitudinal dataset with 10 subjects"
> 
> # verify with an SQL query
> 
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf('select count(distinct id) from data')
  count(distinct id)
1                 10
>
```